# How to get id's of those with empty values as well as filled values using inner join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$products = Product::select('products.*','c.name as category_name','b.name as brand_name')
                        ->join('categories as c','products.category_id','c.id')
                        ->join('brands as b','products.brand_id','b.id')
                        ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')
                        ->orderBy('products.created_at','desc')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

The above is the code I am using in laravel to get product details from product table. With the above code I am getting all the products with having brand_id, but I want both products having `brand_id` as well as without `brand_id` (shown in table below) using join.

Below is the product table:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id    |    category_id    | sub_category_id    | brand_id    | title    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     |    3              |     1              |   1         |  abc     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2     |    3              |     3              |   2         |  Shirts  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3     |    3              |     3              |             |  jeans   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4     |    1              |     1              |             |   efg    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the brand table:-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id    |   category_id    |   sub_category_id   |   name    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     |   3              |   1                 |  abc      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2     |   3              |   3                 |  efg      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the Category Table:-

```
-------------------
| id    |  name   |
-------------------
| 1     |  men    |
-------------------
| 2     |  women  |
-------------------
| 3     |  kids   |
-------------------
```

Comment: use leftjoin instead of join.

Comment: @TsaiKoga it worked. thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome.